# Is it correct to say "Could you check my second tooth from the inside on the right of my lower jaw"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

[image]

I have a decayed tooth as shown in the above picture.

**What can I say to let the dentist locate it?**

Can I say "**Could you check my second tooth from the inside on the right of my lower jaw**"?

Comment: I wouldn't risk it. The dentist probably won't know what you're talking about. Just put your fingertip on it. Me, I'd probably think you meant your lateral incisor, because to me "from the inside" suggests "working from the [front] **middle** of the jaw", not "from the **back**".

Comment: No one would say that. You show the dentist with your finger if you can't name the tooth.

Comment: It's verbally the 'left mandibular second molar', and number 18 in the international system, but native speakers don't learn dentists' technical language. You say 'this one' then open your mouth and put your finger on it.

Comment: That tooth is on the right of the diagram, but it would be on the left side of your jaw.

Comment: Not really. No native English speaker would say this. For a start, the tooth is on your left, not your right.  We usually describe parts of our body from our perspective, not from the perspective of a diagram. Perhaps something a bit more natural would be "Can you check my bottom-left back molar?".  A dentist wouldn't call it that however.

Comment: Don't worry about precision: no dentist I know would ever rely on an oral (no pun intended) description of which tooth, not only due to difficulty in *describing* the location, but because the sense of discomfort might appear to be coming from a different location than the actual injury. The dentist would tap each tooth in the area and/or spray with cold water to locate the problem. Sorry, this is in no way an answer helping with learning English.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not an issue in learning English.  You simply don't identify teeth in this way.  It is not your job to identify the bad tooth. It is the dentist's job.  So there is no answer for this. The situation in which you need to identify a tooth to a dentist who can't identify a bad tooth, and who can only listen and not ask question simply does not occur.

Comment: I'd say something like "Second from the back on the left, bottom", but also point (at least from the outside). "Inside" is a weird description - they're all inside your mouth. (Similarly you wouldn't describe a door in a corridor as "second from the inside".)

Answer (score 1):

You say "I have a toothache", and when the dentist asks "where?" you point.

You can use general terms like "lower left".

It's not your job to know dentist jargon, or have an unambiguous way to name your teeth. You just need to answer the dentist's questions. Identifying which tooth is damaged is the dentist's job, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can save all this guesswork naming by simply using numbers. That's what the dentist does.

Second tooth from the inside… inside of what?  From the back or the front?
This is just confusing.
Even the tooth your arrow is pointing to isn't on your right, it's on your left.

The tooth you mean is simply **'lower right seven'**. That's how the dentist will refer to it.
They're facing you, so they use **your** right and left, not theirs.

You start to count from your central incisors; left and right, upper and lower. Each of those is 'one'. So you only have 1 through 8 in each quarter [including 'wisdom' teeth, which not all people have]. You count any missing teeth too. The numbering doesn't skip a tooth if it's not there.

Of course, pointing & mumbling around your own hand "iff wun, hurtff" will probably get the message across just as well ;))

Comment: The tooth marked on the picture is the lower *left* seven. It's the patient's right and left that counts, always. (Whether the asker made a mistake in the picture or the description, I don't know.)

Comment: @Divizna - The OP said it's their right. I already pointed out the picture shows left.

Comment: I'm just not so convinced it's necessarily the picture that's wrong. They could've been trying to "helpfully" describe it from the dentist's point of view (which is of course the opposite of helpful because every dentist knows that "right" means patient's right and patient's left is called "left").

Comment: @Divizna - I guess we'll never know unless the OP comes back to tell us.